# The word 'City' breaks my layout in Safari only

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, web-frontend

I have discovered what appears to be a very odd behaviour in Safari and I cannot figure out what is going on.

**My layout as viewed in Chrome:**

[image: Screenshot of a portion of my HTML Form viewed in Chrome]

**But when viewed in Safari I get the following:**

[image: Screenshot of a portion of my HTML Form viewed in Chrome]

For some bizarre reason the `<small class="text-muted">(required)</small>` portion of my HTML has been dropped to a new line.

Even more bizarrely, if I just change one letter in the word 'City', the layout becomes correct.

**The same portion of my form but I have literally changed one thing and that is that I've changed the word 'City' to instead say 'Sity':**

[image: The same portion of my form but I have changed the word 'City' to instead say 'Sity']

In fact, I seem to be able to use any word instead of 'City', but when I use the word 'City', the label suddenly takes up 2 lines. So, in light of this, there is an easy fix which is to just use the word 'Town' instead of the word 'City' but I would still like to know if this is just a really strange bug or if I'm missing something.

*What on earth is going on here?*

I was unable to recreate this issue in stack overflow's code snippet tool.

I am using Bootstrap 4 and the portion of HTML that I'm looking at is as follows:

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="form-group needs-validation col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <label for="inputCity">City <small class="text-muted">(required)</small></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity" name="city" required>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Please provide your city.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group needs-validation col-sm-6 col-md-4">
    <label for="inputState">State <small class="text-muted">(required)</small></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputState" name="state" required
              autocomplete="address-level1">
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Please provide your state.
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group needs-validation col-5 col-sm-4 col-md-2">
    <label for="inputZip">Zip <small class="text-muted">(required)</small></label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip" name="zip" required>
    <div class="invalid-feedback">
      Please provide your zip code.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT Responding to Comments**

@Rdg Replacing the space with `&nbsp;` does indeed fix the layout. But why does this only occur when followed by the word 'City' and nothing else (granted I haven't tested every word in the English language, so could it be something to do with the exact width of the word 'City'?)

@Geuis Yes I have finally managed to recreate this in codepen, it seems to be an issue with the font I am using ("Raleway") and the exact width of the word "City". https://codepen.io/Redtama/pen/RdRpqX

@Richard Uie I'm not sure what you mean by `substitute the HTML entity for uppercase "c," i.e., &amp;#67;`, but with regards to the wrapping being caused by width, I can replace the word 'City' with something much longer and no wrapping takes place.

**Example with Longer Label Text**
[image: Same portion of the form but with a longer label]

Comment: Strange indeed. Have your tried adding `&nbsp` next to city. A black space html ? Maybe this solves it.

Comment: Could you create a codepen for this that demonstrates the problem live?

Comment: Seems obvious that the width of context in which your "C" is place forces a wrapping. How that behavior is being driven is NOT obvious. Do you encounter the weird result, if you substitute the HTML entity for uppercase "c," i.e., &amp;#67;?

Comment: @RichardUie Check my EDIT :) Also here is the codepen where I managed to recreate the issue. https://codepen.io/Redtama/pen/RdRpqX

Comment: @Geius Yes! https://codepen.io/Redtama/pen/RdRpqX

Comment: @Rdg Yes that does fix it. Check my edits for more info. Interestingly moving the space to be inside the small tag instead of immediately after the word "City" also fixes it. i.e `City<small class="text-muted"> **space here** (required)</small>`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding the following to your css forcing the text to become an inline element:

```
.text-muted {
  display: inline-block;
}
```